# How to get list billing address and list shipping address based on customer id

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

Please, can someone tell me, how to get list shipping addresses and billing addresses the specific customer by customer id in Magento 1.9?

Thanks.

Comment: is your question solved?

Comment: still not yet, I need all list customer address besides default billing and shipping address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$customerId = 2;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$defaultBilling  = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
$defaultShipping = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

$allAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->setCustomerFilter($customer);

foreach ($allAddress as $address) {
    if($defaultBilling == $address->getId()) {
        // its customer default billing address
    } else if($defaultShipping == $address->getId()) {
        // its customer default shipping address
    } else {
        // its customer other address that saved
    }
}
```

Comment: this code more complete than mine, I will accept this as answer. hope next could help someone which have same trouble with me in future. Thank you very much @Sohel Rana

Answer (score 1):

```
please use the below code:

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$defaultBilling  = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$defaultShipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need all address besides default billing address and default shipping address

Answer (score 1):

I had solved my problem,

this is my code, to get all address based customer id :

```
$customer_id = 1; //example
$customerdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

foreach ($customerdata->getAddresses() as $address)
{
$addr = $address->toArray();
echo $addr['street'];
echo $addr['telephone'];
//....
}
```

Thank you for all